# Add html icon in button value

Tags: html

```
<input type="submit" id="appCreate" name="Reds" value="Reds" formaction=@Url.Action("") formmethod="post" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="javascript: return SubmitForm(this);" />
```

CSS -

```
.reddot {
  content: "\25cf";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
}
```

I want to add `<span class="reddot"></span>` to the value of my button (it just creates a red dot icon).   So the value of my button shown is `Reds<red dot icon>`

How can I do this?

Comment: @TylerRoper Right, but what would the work around be? Is it impossible to show a reddot inside a button?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment. You're trying to have a red dot at the end of the button text? Or is the red dot always in the same place on the button, regardless of its text?

Comment: Well preferably a right aligned reddot, while the text is left aligned.  But I would also be fine with the reddot just being after the text. @TylerRoper

Comment: The red dot being right-aligned is much easier than the latter. I'll submit an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `content: "\25cf";` Try `background: url('xyz.png');`

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` elements are considered *void* elements, therefore they cannot contain children. You *could* use a `<button>` element, but personally I'd discourage this method because the HTML spec deems it invalid.

One possible solution is to wrap the button in a container. That container could have a pseudo-element ([`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)) that places the red dot for you.

```css
.reddot {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.reddot > input[type=submit] {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 20px;         /* Add padding to make space for the dot */
}

.reddot::after {               /* Place an element inside of .reddot */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* Center it vertically */
  right: 5px;                  /* 5px off the right edge */
  content: "\25cf";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;        /* Make sure the dot doesn't block the button */
}
```

```html
<div class="reddot">
  <input type="submit" />
</div>

<div class="reddot">
  <input type="submit" value="Here's another button with a red dot!" />
</div>
```